# What is the model of the Emachines Etower 366i2's Monitor?

Tags: restoration, crt-monitor

I've an old 1999 Emachines Etower I want to restore. I have all the original parts except for the monitor. It just isn't a complete set without it. Does anybody know the specific model of that monitor? Most of this model had white or grey written on their labels. My computer is the much rarer beige color. That does not mean it still looks beige, but it's supposed to be beige.

I tried Emachines' website and I think it was an old Cathode Ray Tube Monitor. Also, this was not purchased separately; it was a bundle. So please tell me the original model.

Comment: Welcome to Retrocomputing Stack Exchange. Thanks for the question; hopefully it'll get answered soon. In the meantime you could have a look at our [tour] to learn the basics of how Stack Exchange works, or read a bit on [meta.retrocomputing.se] to see how *this* site works. And, of course, if you know the answers to any of the questions here, don't hesitate to post them! If you have any questions, just `@wizzwizz4` reply to this comment.

Comment: I'm still giggling over "much rarer beige color" .

Comment: Monitors were sold separately, although various bundles offered lower combined prices.  Almost certainly CRT, although by 2003 they offered LCD.ones. I had a 1999 366cs with 12-in color CRT.

Comment: The eMachines eView 15s is [from that time period](https://books.google.com/books?id=M7xcio3J5KkC&lpg=PA173&ots=O989To8yyK&dq=emachines%2015s&pg=PA173#v=onepage&q=emachines%2015s&f=false), also maybe the eView 14.